# Регулярные выражения по списку из Memo

Tags: delphi

Как можно, **из Memo**, подключить **список регулярных выражений** и обработать ими файл.

**Суть вопроса:** в **Memo1** есть список регулярных выражений (**в столбик**), есть текстовый файл. Нужно, **из файла**, вытянуть определенные строки, **используя список регулярных выражений из Memo1**. И в результате сохранить обработанный файл.

Предоставленный код работает, только с первым регулярным выражением (**А нужно что бы работал по списку**) что в Memo1.

Я старался и полностью описал весь код, **но вот что не так не пойму ?**

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
NaVhod, NaVihod: TextFile;
S: string;
m_Reg: array of string;
i: integer;
RegExp:TRegExpr;
begin

// Подключаем RegExp
RegExp:=TRegExpr.Create;

//Открываем файл
if OpenDialog1.Execute then
begin
     // Открываем входной файл
     AssignFile(NaVhod, OpenDialog1.FileName);
     reset(NaVhod);

     // Записываем выходной файл
     AssignFile(NaVihod, ExtractFileDir(OpenDialog1.FileName)+'\NaVihod.txt');
     rewrite(NaVihod);

     // Берем (в цикле) регулярные выражения из списка memo1
     for I := 0 to Memo1.Lines.Count -1 do
     begin
     RegExp.Expression:=Memo1.lines[i];
     end;

     //Проходим по строкам
 while not Eof(NaVhod) do
  begin

 //читаем входной файл
  ReadLn(NaVhod, S);

 // Применяем регулярные выражения из memo к строкам входного файла
  if(RegExp.Exec(S)) then
 // Записываем выходной файл
   writeln(NaVihod, S);
  end;

  // Закрываем входной файл
CloseFile(NaVhod);
 // Закрываем выходной файл
CloseFile(NaVihod);
end;
end;

end.
```

Comment: Что будет в `RegExp.Expression` после этого цикла `for I := 0 to Memo1.Lines.Count -1 do`?

Comment: @Igor, Получается цикл смешает все, но если цикл убрать и поставить RegExp.Expression:=Memo1.Text то по сути дела не работает. Как же тогда правильно ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
while not Eof(NaVhod) do
begin
  //читаем входной файл
  ReadLn(NaVhod, S);

  // Берем (в цикле) регулярные выражения из списка memo1
  for I := 0 to Memo1.Lines.Count -1 do
  begin
    RegExp.Expression:=Memo1.lines[i];
    // Применяем регулярные выражения из memo к строкам входного файла
    if(RegExp.Exec(S)) then
    begin
      // Записываем выходной файл
      writeln(NaVihod, S);
      break;
    end;
  end;
end;
```